# SAS/STAT PROC GLM procedure. Using Nuisance factor

Tags: sas, linear-regression

I am trying to learn the statistics procedures in SAS through EG. Ofcouse not sure how far modeling is performed from EG itself these days.

In PROC GLM, comparing multiple samples using a categorical variable VENDOR name. I am comparing mean hourly bill rate for various consulting firms. At 95% confidence level there is no much difference in means. But when I consider the technology/skill set as another categorical variable, then the P value is going below 0.05. I just included skill_set in the class and model statements on the PROC GLM.

Can this be a true statistical analysis? The SGPLOT graphs for each sample when I include both the categorical variables Vendor names and Skill_sets are following normal distribution.

But as I am including two categorical variables, the defendant variable bill_rate is not independent on each categorical variable separately. Also, I am not sure if I can consider skill_set as a Nuisance factor.

Comment: Yes, this is fine. As long as it meets the assumptions of simple linear regression, your analysis is valid.

Comment: Here I didn't use the randomized design within the sample. Anyway the error decreased after introducing the second category variable